# How to have html in TinyMce "Text" tab properly indented and highlighted

Tags: tinymce

Is there a way to have the "Text" tab of tinyMce display a properly indented and highlighted/formatted HTML?

Is there any solution to achieve this?

Comment: Nicola, what did you try yourself? If, then show some code and please do not ask for a plugin.

Comment: @Nicola http://bfy.tw/3ozc